# (How) can I open the result of a form submission in a new window?

Tags: html, forms

I have a small form inside a table.  POSTing that form creates a new entity.  I then want users to see that new entity, but it should open in a new window so that the original view isn't lost.

(How) can I open the result of the form submission in a new window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form ... target="windowName">
```

or

```
<form ... target="windowName" onsubmit="window.open(this.action, this.target, '...attributes...');return true;">
```

...attributes... can consist of the stuff documented at the [mozilla developer center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open#Position_and_size_features) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651.aspx)

Comment: Here's some documentation on form.target: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

One request, one response.  That is the way of the web.

If you want a new window after a post, you either need to post the request from the new window in the first place- perhaps opened via javascript- or post your data from that page to the *same* page and save a token so that when the page re-loads is can open a new windows -again, likely with javascript- and that new window's request already knows about the previous post.